# Magento Multiple Storefront Canada Origin Fedex Rates

Tags: e-commerce, magento-1.7, magento

I have searched high and low to find that a few other users (not in stack) have been having the same niche problem as myself. Unfortunately, the issue I have run into is FedEx rates not pulling for Canada on the administrative users on a multiple storefront Magento setup.

Let me clarify,

I am running Magento 1.7.0.1 multiple storefronts.
One storefront is for the United States, the other is for Canada.
Rates pull properly for the United States (both front-end, user-based side, and administrative), and they also pull properly for Canada (front end, user-based side), but not the Administrative side.

I have done an immense amount of research to reveal that the reason the rates are not available is because the Canadian Administrative system is attempting to pull rates for USD, instead of CAD, where the front end of the website pulls CAD properly.

Please help out if at all possible, or I may rip my hair out. Everything (should) be set properly in the configurable options, since I have done multiple storefronts and many Magento based stores in the past, with great success.

Thank you all so much,
Tony